# Who drew the Wendimoor mural

Tags: dirk-gently

In S2:E09 of *Dirk Gently’s Holistic Detective Agency*, we find out that in the ‘throne room’ (or whatever exactly it is) in Wendimoor, there are mural drawings of Earth, similar to the ones of Wendimoor in The Boy’s bedroom on Earth.

As far as I’ve been able to follow the story, the ones on Earth were drawn by The Boy

> as a sort of ‘preparation’ for the fantasy world he wanted to create, and eventually did create, though not quite as he’d planned it.

But what about the ones in Wendimoor? Who drew them? The obvious answer would be The Boy, but

> The Boy never actually went to Wendimoor: he created it with that big energy surge in 1967, and the act of creation put him into a lifelong coma, during which he obviously couldn’t visit Wendimoor (or the prophecy foretelling his appearance wouldn’t make sense) and, by his own words, couldn’t create things either.

So who drew them? Were they just there as an inherent part of Wendimoor since the beginning of time?

Answer (score 1):

At least one inhabitant of Wendimoor (Wakti Wapnasi) has the ability to (fore)see the events of our world.
As to why this is, see [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/178917/20840).
This suggests that the murals were drawn by Wakti Wapnasi, somebody instructed or inspired by her, or another Wendimoorean with visionary capabilities.

As to why the murals were drawn, well, what would you do to fixate visions that are essential to the fate of your world?
I don’t remember whether Wendimoor had written language and even if it did, its creator, the Boy, preferred to draw things (as evidenced by the mural in our world).

Comment: Does it, though? I mean, yes, Wakti had some sort of ability to prophesy future events, in both worlds, but is there anything to indicate that she had any idea about the boat, the purple monster thingy, or any of the other stuff on the murals? Even if she did, why would she draw them on murals in Wendimoor? The only advantage there might be would be to help Dirk solve the case, but if she knew that he’d arrive in the throne room and need hints, she’d also know he’d meet Amanda soon after and could just have given her the same info…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: See my edit.